# Why is google bot getting NullReferenceException when crawling my site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have installed some error logging onto my ASP.NET MVC site and I have been getting a lot of NullReferenceException errors when google crawls my site.

But when I go to the URL that generated the error there is nothing wrong?

Why would this be happening? Why would the google bot be causing an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something requiring cookies or a session or something else that Google doesn't support? Can you get any more information about the error from the event log?

Comment: Thanks that was actually the reason I guess I need to pay more attention to my code, I was checking for a cookie that obviously google bot wouldn't have... doh!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe missing cookie or referrer? Check for any dependency to optional HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

Bots don't contain a whole lot of things that browsers do. For example you may be checking for a session variable that doesn't exist.